# Как удалить объект из массива объектов по его свойству?

Tags: php, ооп

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться, недавно подступился к ООП на php, занятие на использование объектов одного класса методами другого. Задание звучит следующим образом: "Реализуйте в классе Cart метод remove для удаления продуктов. Метод должен принимать параметром название удаляемого продукта.". Вод код, который у меня получился:

```
<?php
class Product
{
    private $name;
    private $price;
    private $quantity;

    public function __construct($name, $price, $quantity)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->quantity = $quantity;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }
    public function getCost()
    {
        return $this->price * $this->quantity;
    }
}

class Cart
{
    private $products = [];

    public function add($product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;
    }
    public function getCart()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
    public function remove($name)
    {
        $products = $this->products;
        foreach($products as $object => $name)
        {
            if(!empty(array_keys($products[$object], $name)))
            {
                unset($products[$object]);
            }
        }
    }
}

$product1 = new Product('sugar', 25, 10);
$product2 = new Product('meat', 250, 5);
$cart = new Cart;
$cart->add($product1);
$cart->add($product2);


echo '<pre>';
print_r($cart->getCart());
echo '</pre>';

$cart->remove('meat');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($cart->getCart());
echo '</pre>';
```

Всё бы хорошо, да только php справедливо ругается, что функция array_keys должна первым параметром принимать массив, а я ей даю объект: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in C:\OSPanel\domains\oop-and-mvc\133-passing-objects-by-parameters\Product.php on line 49.

Собственно, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Есть ли более подходящая функция, или может быть можно решить задачу как-то иначе? У меня уже, кажется, мозг отказывается работать.

Comment: Вариантов много.. Ты можешь реализовать внутри не нумерованный массив `$products` а ассоциативный, где ключом будет имя, а значением - объект. Тогда в методе remove  можно будет просто брать значение по ключу, т.е. `unset($products[$name])`. Этот вариант имеет недостатки, но всё же лучше, чем ничего)

Comment: А раз ты удаляешь по имени, то тебе `array_keys` вообще не нужен, надо писать просто `foreach($products as $index => $object) if($object->name === $name) { unset($products[$index]) }`  .......... и foreach у тебя неправильный.... потому что в виде ключа будет индекс а не object

Comment: А ещё у тебя конфликт имён...... у тебя параметр в методе назван так же, как в цикле foreach... в итоге тот что в цикле перетирает внешний... и в строке `if(!empty(array_keys($products[$object], $name)))`   подставляется `$name` не из параметра метода, а из цикла foreach

Comment: @АлексейШиманский блин, точно, я в массиве запутался вообще, не понял даже, что там ещё индекс есть, спасибо! Только теперь у меня не получается обратиться к свойству $object->name, потому как оно приватное для класса Product, это можно как-то пофиксить не делая его публичным?

Comment: взгляни внимательно на свой же класс Product и увидишь как можно имя взять без обращения свойства в публичное))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский точно спать пора, уже вообще не соображаю кажется) Да, я понял, это должно выглядеть вот так: if($object->getName() === $name). Только не понял, почему вот так это работает: `foreach($this->products as $index => $object) {if($object->getName() === $name) { unset($this->products[$index]); }}` 
А вот так - нет: ` $products = $this->products; foreach($products as $index => $object) { if($object->getName() === $name) { unset($products[$index]); } }`

Comment: да....... и при всех раскладах в строчке кода `$products = $this->products;` нет смысла..... везде просто использовать `$this->products`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хорошо, просто запомню, что так не делается, спасибо ещё раз большое, второй день выручаешь)